# how to decode G711 audio packet C#

Tags: c#, audio, decode, voip

I am developing a voip type app in which i am capturing G711 packets from the network. Now i need to decode them and need to save it in .wav format and able to listen it. Any sample code or direction which can lead to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

g711 is just standard uLaw or aLaw codec, for which there is lots of examples out there.

For example, Mark Sweetgall has an [implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/g711audio.aspx) in C# available over on CodeProject.